# Default text as well as list textvariable Entry widget Tkinter

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I have the following Entry box where due to obtaining values I have put a list option in for textvariable.

However I was wondering if it would be possible to put a default text in the background so to show which values are required in each box (like a greyscale text, 'Value 1, value 2 etc..).

```
self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(self.number_boxes) ] #Name available in global scope.       
box=Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i])
```

Can I add in maybe something change 'textvariable' upon a mouse click inside the box or can I simply just add in another textvariable or text to set a default text?

```
  self.box = []

  for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):

        self.clicked = False
        self.box.append(Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i], fg='grey'))
        self.box[i].grid(row=row_list,column=column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
        self.box[i].insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
        self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't used pack or grid with a list though. =S

Comment: Ok, I've got it but it only seems to work with the first box in the callback. I can't use box[i] with the append line, the others are all ok..I get the same error with append 'list out of range'.

Comment: You will have to learn lamba functions so that you can pass `i` to the callback function. The callback will change to accept `i` as an input parameter: `def callback(event, i):` in the function definition and `box[i]` in the body of the callback. Search stackoverflow for examples of lamba functions. Best of luck.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll check out your other questions when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to put default text in your `Entry` widget, you can use the `insert()` method as described [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method).

```
box.insert(0, "Value 1")    # Set default text at cursor position 0.
```

Now in order to change the contents of `box` after the user performs a mouse click inside the box, you will need to *bind* an event to the `Entry` object. For example, the following code deletes the contents of the box when it is clicked. (You can read about event and bindings [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).) Below I show a full example of this.

Note that deleting the text in the box is probably only practical for the first click (i.e. when deleting the default contents), so I created a global flag `clicked` to keep track of whether it has been clicked.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, END    # Python3. For Python2.x, import Tkinter.

# Use this as a flag to indicate if the box was clicked.
global clicked   
clicked = False

# Delete the contents of the Entry widget. Use the flag
# so that this only happens the first time.
def callback(event):
    global clicked
    if (clicked == False):
        box[0].delete(0, END)         #  
        box[0].config(fg = "black")   # Change the colour of the text here.
        clicked = True

root = Tk()
box = []                              # Declare a list for the Entry widgets.

box.append(Entry(fg = "gray"))        # Create an Entry box with gray text.
box[0].bind("<Button-1>", callback)   # Bind a mouse-click to the callback function.
box[0].insert(0, "Value 1")           # Set default text at cursor position 0.

box.append(Entry(fg = "gray"))        # Make a 2nd Entry; store a reference to it in box.
box[1].insert(0, "Value 2")

box[0].pack()                         #
box[1].pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this work in conjunction with my other input 'textvariable'? Can I insert box["textvariable"] = self.numbers[i] following deleting the contents in the callback or would that not work?

Comment: Also I am using grid as I've integrated it into my code but nothing happens when I click inside the box. I've been using a class and self. so I used self.box. The textvariable still seems to work. Also in the callback, can I simply change the colour back to black for the inserted text?

Comment: I've actually managed to correct it in class and it works like a normal instance self.clicked. I however have the problem where I've created several entry boxes using a loop and it only affects the last one =( You don't happen to know how I would create 'separate' boxes?

Comment: @user2063 Sure, just create a list to store references to your Entry objects. See my edited post for a simple example of that. Hope it helps. (It would need its own binding event...)

Comment: Could I repeat this in a loop using 'i' as I have a random number of boxes and therefore can't specific '1 or 2 etc'. I'm not an expert but would box[i] work if I could enter the number of boxes via a user input?

Comment: @user2063 Yes, `box[i]` is valid. You should definitely implement a loop when you have code that applies to each Entry object. The trick will be inserting different text and (more so) binding events that differ with each box. For event binding, look into lamba functions - in line functions in which you can pass a variable to the callback function. In your loop, the variable `i` would identify each box in the list, so you would pass it to the callback function so it can operate on each box individually.

Comment: See my edited code in question, this however returns 'list index out of range' and I don't really understand. I've looked at lambda before but have never understood it.

Comment: Put `self.box = []` outside (before) the loop. Then do `self.box.append(...)` You get an error using `i` here since the list is empty... (until you append something to it). Then using `i` in the next line of code is OK.