# Python TextBox entry Hint(Invisible text)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a text box with a hint inside of it. Like in the picture below. I tried using Hint and else but it would not work.

[image]

```
master = Tk.Tk() # Open up GUI connection
master.title('Program Application')
Label(text='Correct Range for Gradient').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX1 = Entry(master, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX2 = Entry(master, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
entryY1 = Entry(master,width=10).pack(side=RIGHT,padx=10,pady=10)
entryY2 = Entry(master,width=10).pack(side=RIGHT,padx=10,pady=10)
master.mainloop()
```

## How can i make it to have my text box to have a hint(invisible text) inside

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331079/default-text-as-well-as-list-textvariable-entry-widget-tkinter  . It may help you.