# Entry window in tkinter is not deleting

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working on this code to calculate certain values found in a gcode file. There is one value of volume found in the loaded by a button gcode file and then mass and price are found. I wanted for one to be able to enter those  variables using entry function but that also there are some values as default in the first place. My problem is that the entry window doesn't clear and accept other values, only those default are there. I am using entry.delete(0, END) but it is not working.

This is the code:

```
    def delete_entry(self):
        e.delete(0, END)
        return None

#    def Statusbar(self):
#         self.stat1.set("Waiting for the file... ")

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("Filament Data")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)
        help = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)

        #added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)


        #Creating the  intro label
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Enter density and price per \n gram of your material and then \n load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
        l_instruction.grid(columnspan=2, ipady=10)


        #Creating the button
        gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
        gcodeButton.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, ipady=10)

        #Entry fields for density and price per gram
        e = Entry(self, justify=CENTER, width=5)
#        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, "1.13")
        e.grid(row=1, column=0)
        e.bind("<Button-1>", self.delete_entry)
        self.density = float(e.get())


        e_label = Label(self, text="D")
        e_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        e1 = Entry(self, justify=CENTER, width=5)
#        e1.delete(0, END)
        e1.insert(0, "0.175")
        e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.price = float(e1.get())

        e1_label = Label(self, text="$")
        e1_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: Please try to reduce that code way down to the smallest possible program that illustrates the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The only place in your code where you call the `delete` method of an entry widget is when you first create the widget (and it's created empty, so that has no effect).

Comment: Isn't it created filled with the sample values? That is how I understood it and therefore I placed delete right after. I thought this delete is triggered whenever the mouse is placed in the entry box.

Comment: No, the delete is not triggered whenever the mouse is placed in the entry box. Did you read that in some documentation somewhere? You have to set up that sort of thing yourself by adding bindings to the widget.

Comment: Hmm I think so but I have read so many things in past days, it is possible I mixed something up. So this delete command alone won't work, right? I need to connect it somehow to the entry box ? Could you tell me in which direction I should go because I don't even have ideas anymore for what to google up.

Comment: the delete command does exactly what it says - it deletes the existing contents of the widget. If you want it to delete when you click in the Entry, start by reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34571635/7432

Comment: So now I am deleting things and than immediately inserting the sample text later and not deleting anymore, right? Thanks for the link I will check it out now.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code in main answer taking into the account link you showed me and now when I click on the entry box I get following error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: delete_entry() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: When you create a binding, tkinter always passes in an extra argument: an object representing the event.

Comment: Is there any way around it? As I did exactly as in this example from the link. I have also modified this line `e.bind(self, "<Button-1>", self.delete_entry)` I added `self` now there is no error but also the value is not deleted.

Comment: Here is also very similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331079/default-text-as-well-as-list-textvariable-entry-widget-tkinter and it is solved similar to your link but I still can't figure what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Is there any way around it? Of course. make `delete_entry` accept an extra argument.

Comment: I think I fixed this issue adding `self` to bind option or at least error don't show up, but still the value is not reseted, as I wrote.

Comment: please create an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is too hard to help with a bunch of extra code, and with you changing the code after answers have already been given.

Comment: I really don't know what more is required for MCVE so you accept it. I have posted a part of the code that makes issues, I have described my problem in detail and explained everything. There is a track of our conversation in comments and also I have uploaded a new code for the main question as it has evolved while we had a discussion and you suggested some solutions. I have done this before and It didn't seem like a problem. In previous comments you also seem like you have understood what my problem is.

Comment: Also I really don't think that my post does not show any research effort or is unclear or not useful...

Comment: What is required is the "M" (minimal).  For this problem you need a single entry widget, maybe a button. You don't need the menus, you don't need the labels. You are also missing "C" (complete). We need to see the class definition and the imports. We need to be able to copy your code, paste it into a file, and be able to run the file. Stackoverflow isn't designed for discussions, and changing the question after you get part of an answer.

Comment: I was initaly posting a whole code (which I don't think is too long) because I am a very beginner to python. Not only I don't fully understand all of the initial code settings but also I don't really know for sure which part of the code is wrong to be honest. Previously I had experience that couple of parts of the code were not fitting together. What should I do now, edit this question, create the new one? I have a impression that to be able to test this code you anyhow need most of it as all things are connected. I didn't change the question I have updated the code.

Comment: Beside, you are emphasising for the second time that I am too newbie for stackoverflow. Can you suggest another place with people experienced in python that could help somebody who is not a programer, doesn't program to much, is a total beginer and is just trying to learn new thing?

Comment: You aren't "too newbie", but you need to be able to write better questions and do a little more research, if you want to get good answers. The whole point of creating a MCVE is to help _you_. Experience has taught us that when you take the time to reduce the problem down to the smallest amount of code possible, the answer often reveals itself to you. And if it doesn't, the question is more likely to be answered because the problem is easy to reproduce. If your problem is with an entry widget, try removing the label and menu widgets to validate your assumptions that it's the entry widget.

Comment: Well that make sense, as I said also yesterday, I do understand rules and all on such a websites as this one. But just sometimes the cases are a bit nonstandard. Anyhow thanks for the input. Shall I make a new question?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `delete` method, it immediately deletes whatever is in the widget. In your case you are calling it immediately after creating the widget when there is nothing to delete.

If you want the text in an entry widget to be deleted when a user clicks on it, you will need to define a binding that deletes the contents.

To create a binding, call the `bind` method of the widget, and tell it the event to bind to, and the function to call. For example, if you want to call the function `delete_entry`, you can do it like this:

```
def delete_entry(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")

e = Entry(...)
e.bind("<1>", delete_entry)
```

When you bind a function to an event, the function will be called with an argument -- an object that represents the event. One of the attributes of the object is `widget`, which is a reference to the widget that owns the event. You can use this reference to interact with the widget.

Comment: But there are some values in the entry box initially as a default numbers so somebody might not choose to alter them. And I understood that this `delete` option is only working when you enter the entry box - I mean try to change the value.

Comment: I have done like this already (after your updated answer) and it didn't work. There are errors while compiling and when I change event to self the errors disappear but entry window is not cleared.

Comment: @Bart: without seeing your code it's impossible to say. Renaming `event` to `self` won't change anything (except force the subsequent use of `event` to fail). However, if you're using classes, `self` is absolutely required _in addition to the event object_. The code in this answer absolutely will work. You should be getting an error message telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I have alredy solved the problem with help of others. The problem was that the whole code is a bit messy and there was a mix up with classes and what does what. In this particular situation I think that me posting a whole code was a good thing in the end as it would be probably really hard to find a mistake in only small parts of code, they would work probably fine but the whole code still wouldn't. Also the fix was super fast it took like 10 min for someone to figure it out and help me, but anyhow thank you for your input and time. Have a good day.